# cut specific columns from several files and reshape using unix tools

Tags: perl, bash, unix, sed, awk

I have several hundred files in a folder. Each of these file is a tab delimited text file that contain more than a million rows and 27 columns. From each file, I want to be able to extract only specific columns (say pull out only columns: 1,2,11,12,13). Columns 3:10 & 14:27 can be ignored. I want to be able to do this for all files in the folder (say 2300 files). The columns from each of the 2300 file looks like this..........

```
Sample.ID      SNP.Name    col3  col10  Sample.Index   Allele1...Forward       Allele2...Forward col14 ....col27      
1234567890_A    rs758676    -     -      1              T                       T                 -     ....col27
1234567890_A    rs3916934   -     -      1              T                       T                 -     ....col27
1234567890_A    rs2711935   -     -      1              T                       C                 -     ....col27
1234567890_A    rs17126880  -     -      1              -                       -                 -     ....col27
1234567890_A    rs12831433  -     -      1              T                       T                 -     ....col27
1234567890_A    rs12797197  -     -      1              T                       C                 -     ....col27
```

The cut columns from the 2nd file may look like this....

```
Sample.ID      SNP.Name    col3  col10  Sample.Index   Allele1...Forward       Allele2...Forward col14 ....col27      
1234567899_C    rs758676    -     -      100            T                       A                 -     ....col27
1234567899_C    rs3916934   -     -      100            T                       T                 -     ....col27
1234567899_C    rs2711935   -     -      100            T                       C                 -     ....col27
1234567899_C    rs17126880  -     -      100            C                       G                 -     ....col27
1234567899_C    rs12831433  -     -      100            T                       T                 -     ....col27
1234567899_C    rs12797197  -     -      100            T                       C                 -     ....col27
```

The cut columns from the 3rd file may look like this....

```
Sample.ID      SNP.Name    col3  col10  Sample.Index   Allele1...Forward       Allele2...Forward col14 ....col27      
1234567999_F    rs758676    -     -      256            A                       A                 -     ....col27
1234567999_F    rs3916934   -     -      256            T                       T                 -     ....col27
1234567999_F    rs2711935   -     -      256            T                       C                 -     ....col27
1234567999_F    rs17126880  -     -      256            C                       G                 -     ....col27
1234567999_F    rs12831433  -     -      256            T                       T                 -     ....col27
1234567999_F    rs12797197  -     -      256            C                       C                 -     ....col27
```

The width of the `Sample.ID`, `Sample.Index` are the same in each file but can change between files. The value of `Sample.ID` is the same within each file but different between files. Each of the cut files have the same values under "SNP.Name" column. The `Sample.Index` column may sometimes be same from different file. The other two columns values `(Allele1...Forward & Allele2...Forward)` may change, and are pasted with " " sep under each `SNP.Name` for each `Sample.ID`.

I finally want to merge (tab-delemited) all the cut columns from the 2300 files into this format ......

```
Sample.Index  Sample.ID     rs758676   rs3916934   rs2711935  rs17126880  rs12831433  rs12797197        
1             1234567890_A  T T         T T         T C         0 0         T T         T C        
200           1234567899_C  T A         T T         T C         C G         T T         T C        
256           1234567999_F  A A         T T         T C         C G         T T         C C
```

In simple terms I want to be able to convert a long format into wide format based on the `Sample.ID` column. This is similar to `reshape` function in R. I tried this with R and it runs out of memory and is really slow. Can anyone help with unix tools?

When reshape.sh was applied to 20 files... it produced a spurious "Samples line" in the output. The first 4 fields are featured here.

```
Sample.Index    Sample.ID   rs476542    rs7073746   
1234567891_A          11         C C          A G   
1234567892_A         191         T C          A G   
1234567893_A         204         T C          G G   
1234567894_A          15         T C          A G   
1234567895_A         158         T T          A A   
1234567896_A         208         T C          A A   
1234567897_A         111         T T          G G   
1234567898_A         137         T C          G G   
1234567899_A         216         T C          A G   
1234567900_A         113         T C          G G   
1234567901_A         152         T C          A G   
1234567902_A         178         C C          A A   
1234567903_A         135         C C          A A   
1234567904_A         125         T C          A A   
1234567905_A         194         C C          A A   
1234567906_A         110         C C          G G   
1234567907_A         126         C C          A A   
Sample         -                                    
1234567908_A         169         C C          G G   
1234567909_A         173         C C          G G   
1234567910_A         168         T C          A A
```

Comment: A little known tool that can be useful in situations like this is `paste(1)` which is sort of the opposite of `cut`.

Comment: @Ibrahim...how can `paste(1)` be used in this situation. I understand `paste()` can be used as `rbind` to concatenate all the files. Bu then it needs to be reshaped in the format given.

Comment: The source file format is not quite clear to me. You're saying it's tab-delimited, but you're also saying the field with may vary between files, implying that you're dealing with fixed-width formats.

Comment: @Michael...using `tab-deleimited` separation, I was able to load the data correctly into `R`. Maybe multiple tabs if the `width` gets too long for one tab or maybe the `width` is not longer than the `tab` space..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '

BEGIN {
  maxInd = length("Sample.Index")
  maxID  = length("Sample.ID")
}

FNR>11 && $2 ~ "^rs" {
  SNP[$2]
  key[$11,$1]
  val[$2,$11,$1]=$12" "$13
  maxInd = (len=length($11)) > maxInd ? len : maxInd
  maxID  = (len=length($1))  > maxID  ? len : maxID
}

END {
  printf("%-*s\t%*s\t", maxInd, "Sample.Index", maxID, "Sample.ID")
  for (rs in SNP)
    printf("%s\t", rs)
  printf("\n")

  for(pair in key) {
    split(pair,a,SUBSEP)
      printf("%-*s\t%*s\t", maxInd, a[1], maxID, a[2])
      for(rs in SNP) {
        ale = val[rs,a[1],a[2]]
        out = ale == "- -" ||  ale == "" ? "0 0" : ale
        printf("%*s\t", length(rs), out)
      }
      printf("\n")
  }
}' DNA*.txt
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ ./reshapeDNA
Sample.Index       Sample.ID    rs2711935       rs10829026      rs3924674       rs2635442       rs715350        rs17126880      rs7037313       rs11983370      rs6424572       rs7055953       rs758676        rs7167305       rs12831433      rs2147587       rs12797197      rs3916934       rs11002902
11              1234567890_A          T T              0 0            C C             0 0            0 0               T C            0 0              C C            T G             0 0            C C              0 0              T C            A G              T T            T C              G G
111             1234567892_A          T T              T C            C C             0 0            0 0               C C            T C              C C            T T             0 0            C C              0 0              T T            A A              T T            T T              G G
1               1234567894_A          T T              0 0            T C             C C            A G               C C            0 0              C C            0 0             T C            C C              T T              T T            A G              T T            C C              G G
12              1234567893_A          T T              0 0            C C             T C            A A               T C            0 0              C C            0 0             T T            C C              T G              T C            A G              T T            T C              G G
15              1234567891_A          T T              C C            C C             0 0            0 0               C C            C C              C C            T T             0 0            C C              0 0              T C            A G              T T            T T              G G
```

Comment: @ Siege ...Thanks for the code. I will be able to understand it better with code. Can you tell me which part of the code output the results to a separate file?

Comment: @user simply use redirection for that. If you named the code file `reshapeDNA` like I did, then it would simply be done by issuing the following command: `./reshapeDNA > /path/to/separate/file`

Comment: @user question, is it possible that you may have holes in your output matrix?  That is to say for a given `[Fam.ID,Ind.ID]` pair, some `SNP.Name`'s will have allele values and others won't. Is that possible?

Comment: @SiegeX.. yeas that is possible. Some Ind.ID may not have any allele values. Each empty value may be "-".

Comment: @SiegeX... seems like this works after the 1000 files have been cut and saved as different files. Can that be included as part of the code? Also will this work if the column headers in the cut files are not the same as the ones I have used here? Thanks

Comment: @user I'll update the code to account for holes in the matrix as well as column headers.  Then we can discuss the cut process.

Comment: @user another question, is the first column always 5 digits and the 2nd column always SCAT followed by a 3 digit number? Essentially what I'm asking is if the max width of the first 2 columns are known, and if so, what are the widths?

Comment: @SiegeX....no, the column length is fixed only for the 2nd column (The max width of the 2nd column is 8). In the example I gave you, the 2nd column had "SCAT" followed by 3 digits. But in the actual files they are different (combination of letters and numbers with constant width of 8). The 1st column may have different length, and different format (combination of letters or numbers).

Comment: @user one more question. If an entire row with `[Fam.ID,Ind.ID]` pair doesn't have any allele values (i.e. columns 3 and beyond are all '-') do you want to suppress that row from being output?

Comment: @SiegeX ...That is very unlikely, as my actual data with a million or more SNP.Names (consequently million or more columns in the output) will not all be empty. No I do not want to suppress them in any of the columns. Maybe if possible put "0 0" instead of the allele values where empty.

Comment: @user in that case I think better to just keep all columns as `-` because checking for when to put `0 0` will take up quite a bit more memory to save state for little gain

Comment: @user looking at your updated example, do your files *already* have the `-` as updated? I ask because I have already changed my code (not pasted yet) to produce the `-` if a `[Fam.ID,Ind.ID]` pair doesn't have any values with your original example files.

Comment: @SiegeX..I am not sure if I was clear. In the output column 1 , the values may be of different length. But in each of the cut files they will be the same

Comment: @user is the `Ind.ID` column identical for each record within an individual file as shown?  The problem I'm having is that my program will try to output the pairs `[11111,SCAT125]`,`[22222,SCAT123]` and `[22222,SCAT124]` for the 3 input files given and they will have no values.  Are these pairs impossible or just a quirk of the example files?

Comment: @SiegeX...yes, within each file "Fam.ID" and "Ind.ID" will be the same.

Comment: @SiegeX... Not sure what you are asking in the second part of your last question.

Comment: @SiegeX....[11111,SCAT125],[22222,SCAT123] and [22222,SCAT124] combination are not part of the three input files. So they should not be part of the output file. Consider this situation as a family with many individuals in each family. Each file is for one individual, but many individuals can be part of a family. If Fam.ID column is creating a problem, I can remove this column out of the whole question. This column is not important.

Comment: @user I'll post updated code & output so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @SiegeX....[11111,SCAT125],[22222,SCAT123] and [22222,SCAT124] rows should not be part of the output

Comment: @user Let me see what I can do first to only allow [Fam.ID,Ind.ID] pairs that exist per-file. If it gets too complicated, then we can resort to throwing out the Fam.ID column

Comment: @SiegeX...that seems correct. Thanks. Any reason why the SNP.Name order is changed in the columns/ That is not a big problem for me though.

Comment: @user a quirk of `awk`.  I believe there is a `gnu` extension to alter that behavior although I don't know it off the top of my head.

Comment: @user out of curiosity, how long does it take to run my script across your hundreds of files? Also, I'm curious what the NxM size of the resulting matrix was and how many megabytes the resulting file was.

Comment: @SiegeX...I have not run it yet. I need to cut these individual files from the original file. I have to incorporate a cut command before running your script

Comment: @SiegeX...I know the final output file will be 2926 X 1055374 as there are 2926 individual files and 1055372 SNPs in each file.

Comment: @user you could put a separate question on SO on how to cut fields from one file to make many files. awk could do it fairly easily if the set of fields per file are equally spaced.

Comment: @SiegeX...I was thinking of modifying your code to apply directly to the original file without a preceding cut command. I am assuming I have to change the $1, $2, $4, $5 based on the location of Sample.ID, SNP.Name, AlleleA and AlleleB in the original file

Comment: @user Update your question to include 4-5 rows (including the header row) of your original file. I can then alter my code to accommodate that.  Its a bit more changes than just altering $1, $2 etc.

Comment: @SiegeX...will do once I reach home. On the east coast!! appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @ SiegeX...I have update the question and example input/output files. The column headers have been changed to reflect actual senario. _Ind.ID_ changed to _Sample.ID_. And _Fam.ID_ changed to _Sample.Index_

Comment: @Dennis thanks, for some reason this one question got me really intrigued

Comment: @SiegeX....what if the first 10 lines of each of these files are junk, and the 11th line is the _Header_ line. How to throw the first 10 lines before running this script? I tried by changing the first line of the script NR==11. This seems to run, but the output has some lines from the first 10 lines.

Comment: @user glad to help out a worthy cause. As for your question on how to skip the first 10 lines, you would do `NR>10{...}`. In `awk` NR stands for Number of Records which by default a record is delimited by a newline. When you did `NR==11` that made it so the code within the adjacent parens `{...}` only worked on the 11th line and skipped the other million lines of input.

Comment: @SiegeX..I removed 10 lines from all files with...                      `for filename in *.txt;
do;
   sed '1,10d' $filename  > tmp.tmp;
   mv tmp.tmp $filename;
   echo "deleted the first 10 lines of" $filename "file";
done`                                                                Applying the `awk` to 20 files produced spurious rows..and the first two columns values are switched.

Comment: @user I see I was confused, I thought you had one large file but I guess you really do have multiple files.  Can you do me a favor and post the first 10 or so lines EXACTLY as they exist (spurious cols and all) of at least 3 files to a site like codepad.org or pastebin.com and then post the link(s) either in a comment or in your question. I'll give them a look when I get home in about an hour

Comment: @SiegeX...how do I share the pastebin.com with just you.

Comment: @user I was hoping you could post a few files without ANY alterations, including the removing of rows 1-10 as well as any removal of rows where $2 has no `rs`. It makes more sense to incorporate these into the awk script as it would not be hard at all.  I can add 10 junk lines to the files your posted, however, I'm curious what a *row without an rs* looks like, can you update your pastebin to include a few of these rows in file #1?

Comment: @user here is the output after some mods to my code (not listed yet) with your 5 files with the addition of 10 junk lines at the top of each http://codepad.org/4eBy3xUy  Note the holes in the matrix, now I can certainly put `0 0` in place of the holes but I don't see where the `- -` you describe come into play?  Also, i suggest you use codepad.org from now on since the formatting is infinity better.  Just choose 'plain text', uncheck 'run code' and checkmark 'private'

Comment: @SiegeX... I have made the following changes 1) Added the first 10 rows of junk lines to each of the 5 files. 2) added rows where $2 does not begin with "rs" (files 4 &5). These rows are not important for my analysis and so can be removed from the output. This is what the _sed_ command does. 3) Some of the $12 and $13 with the SNP values may not have any data, but have `- -`. Incorporated this change to the last two rows of the 1st file. These are the location where `0 0` should go. In addition, `0 0` should go into the holes in the matrix created by unique SNPs in some files.

Comment: @SiegeX... I am not in codepad yet. will have to learn to use codepad

Comment: @user thanks, I'll update the input files and change the script accordingly.  Question, are the `- -` added by some other script or are they already part of the output? I want to be able to move as much as possible into the awk script

Comment: @SiegeX...the `- -` in the $12 and $13 are present in all input files (output of Illumina software, not by any script I wrote) where the actual SNP values could not be determined by the experiment. I am not sure if I got your question correct....I do not want `- -` to be part of the output (of your `awk` script). They should be replaced with `0 0` in the final output.

Comment: @SiegeX...just a reminder..the Sample.Index and Sample.ID values are switched in your output. Thanks

Comment: @user how does this look? http://ideone.com/fLV0C  Still not sure what to do about the holes in the matrix, perhaps those will go away with your real files?

Comment: @SiegeX...the output looks good to me. `0 0` go into the holes in the matrix. Would `sed` work for this purpose? Thank you.

Comment: @user sure, `sed` could work just fine for this but hopefully I've impressed upon you that awk is a very powerful language and any post/pre processing from any of the other unix utilities such as `sed`, `grep`, `cut` etc. can be moved into awk.

Comment: @user see updated answer. This should be all you need to go from illumina output to the format you want.

Comment: @user did a few minor formatting changes. I hard coded the 'Sample.ID' column to a width of 12, is that always correct?

Comment: @SiegeX...no, the 'Sample.ID' width can change.  The max width I have is 17. PLease do not hard code any width if possible. Thanks

Comment: @SiegeX...thank you for persisting with this. Seems to run well on 8 files tested. Will run on the entire dataset (~3000 files) and will let you know the performance. How do I find out the sys.time for running the script?

Comment: @user simply prefix your command line with the word `time` as in:  `time ./reshapeDNA > /path/to/new/file`